# Retrieve another data from mySQL for item recommendation

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am currently doing a recommendation system for my website

I have 4 tables in mySQL database:

Users

- userID
- username
- password
- userLevel

category

- categoryID
- type

item

- itemID
- name
- price
- quantity
- categoryID
- description

transaction

- transactionID
- categoryID
- itemID
- userID

So this is how it I want it works,

userID 1(Kyle) bought Laptop(ItemID 1), Mouse(ItemID 2), and Battery(ItemID 4)

userID 2(Steven) bought Laptop(itemID 1)

userID 3(Jonathan) bought Mouse(ItemID 2), Battery(ItemId 4), and Mousepad(ItemID 3)

I want the system to recommend itemID 2(Mouse), itemID4(Battery), and ItemID 3 (Mousepad) to userID 2(Steven)

- The transaction table will record any transaction made.

Any helps given are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a bit more test data, to make your question clearer...

Comment: Already sir.. I really dont know how to achieve this... Really appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 0):

What the query does is get the All `UserID's` which bought the `ItemID=2`. And then Get the `ItemID` bough by those users. and then apply the filter to remove the `ItemId =2` from the result.Try this.

```
Select distinct ItemID 
FROM transaction 
where UserID IN (Select userID FROM Transaction where itemID = 2 ) 
AND ItemID <> 2
```

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your help
Can I ask you something, what is <> used for?? thanks

Comment: So that the same ItemID will not get selected which in this case 2. That is `Not Equal to` operator.

Comment: Oh i see i see

thanks Sir! I will give a try for the query, thanks!

Comment: Sir do you know how to create a recommendation based on 3 people or more? I have updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
SELECT
    i.itemID,
    i.name,
    u.username
FROM transaction
    INNER JOIN user u ON (u.userID = t.userID)
WHERE u.userID = 2
```

Then you have to work with your language to convert the result to a readable line.

Else you'll have to look for "PIVOT" to convert multiple bought items (multiple lines) to a single line.

An other solution would be to use a transaction with mssql, allowing to parse the results and return a single line.

Comment: How is this supposed to give OP what he wants. Your current query will not give the output OP wants. Check the query before posting it as answer.

Comment: hello Sir thanks for your reply

Iam confused with your "i" and "u". What does that mean actually??
thanks

Comment: I understood the OP wants a list of transactions made by one specific user. Did he want something else? @Foster : You put the same field "userID" in both (transaction and user) tables. When querying, you have to specify to the database which table you want to target when using this field.

Comment: Ahh... I get it Sir.. now it is clear

Thanks so much!